# How to fix <function-style-cast> error: Cannot convert from 'initializer list' to asdendingCompare<W>(template functor)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors

I am trying to use template functor (ascendingCompare) to compare two values and use it in template function (Sort) which sort array

Functor

```
template<typename Q>
class ascendingCompare
{
public:
    bool operator () (const Q &first, const Q &second)
    {
        if (first < second)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
};
```

Sorting function together with function for swaping values

```
template <typename Q>
void Swap(Q &first, Q &second)
{
    Q temp = first;
    first = second;
    second = temp;
}

template <typename W>
void sortAscend(W *arr, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < size - 1 - i; j++)
            if (ascendingCompare<W>( arr[j + 1], arr[j]) )
                Swap(arr[j + 1], arr[j]);
            /*if (arr[j + 1] < arr[j])
                Swap(arr[j + 1], arr[j]);*/
}
```

Part where functor is being used

```
int *sorted_array = new int[array_size]; 
    for (int counter = 0; counter < array_size; counter++)
    {
        sorted_array[counter] = rand() % 100; 
        cout << setw(2) << sorted_array[counter] << "  ";
    }
sortAscend(sorted_array, array_size);
```

So compiler gives this C2440 error : Cannot convert from 'initializer list' to "ascendingCompare"

Comment: You never made an *instance* of `ascendingCompare<W>` before trying to fire `operator()`. Your `ascendingCompare<W>( arr[j + 1], arr[j])` is trying to *construct* from those arguments, which is obviously wrong. Why you're using a function is the real question, since clearly a function template would suffice.

Comment: @WhozCraig Yeah, thanks that did help, as for why i am using this instead of function template just consider a part of the actual task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As answered above

You never made an instance of ascendingCompare before trying to fire operator(). Your ascendingCompare( arr[j + 1], arr[j]) is trying to construct from those arguments, which is obviously wrong.

So the correct form would be

```
template <typename W>
void sortAscend(W *arr, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < size - 1 - i; j++)
            if (ascendingCompare<W>()( arr[j + 1], arr[j]) )
                Swap(arr[j + 1], arr[j]);
            /*if (arr[j + 1] < arr[j])
                Swap(arr[j + 1], arr[j]);*/
}
```

So if you are confused as to what actually changed

old vers

```
if (ascendingCompare<W>( arr[j + 1], arr[j]) )
```

new vers

```
if (ascendingCompare<W>()( arr[j + 1], arr[j]) )
```

Comment: @"Just A Variety",  Just to confirm I understand this, in your answer "new vers", you are not creating an object of the ascendingCompare class. Instead, you are using its function? Is this similar to ClassA::funcA_of_classA ? Could you explain more on what is happening in this expression ?           ascendingCompare<W>()( arr[j + 1], arr[j])